# use regex to filter out specific string in every line

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I would like to filter out only the highlight strings on every line

> **changed: [hostname1] =>** (item={'uid': 1000, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1679196024.843057, 'inode': 1139800, 'isgid': False, 'size': 11745724295, 'roth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True, 'pw_name': 'jira', 'gid': 1000, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True, 'xoth': False, 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp': True, 'gr_name': 'jira', **'path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-18--1900.zip'**
>
> **changed: [hostname2] =>** (item={'uid': 1000, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1679588444.705138, 'inode': 1175380, 'isgid': False, 'size':
> 11834841900, 'roth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True, 'pw_name':
> 'jira', 'gid': 1000, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True, 'xoth': False,
> 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp': True, 'gr_name':
> 'jira', **'path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-23--0801.zip'**
>
> **changed: [hostname3] =>** (item={'uid': 11668, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1679825130.0182097, 'inode': 201355653, 'isgid': False,
> 'size': 20971707, 'roth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True,
> 'pw_name': 'confluence', 'gid': 11668, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True,
> 'xoth': False, 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp':
> True, 'gr_name': 'confluence', **'path':
> '/confluence/home/logs/atlassian-confluence.log.5'**, 'xusr': False,
> 'atime': 1679486655.01409, 'isdir': False, 'ctime':
> 1681368284.8271954, 'isblk': False, 'xgrp': False, 'dev': 64768, 'wgrp': False, 'isfifo': False, 'mode': '0640', 'islnk': False})
>
> **changed: [hostname4] =>** (item={'uid': 11667, 'woth': False, 'mtime': 1680248205.0145996, 'inode': 100784645, 'isgid': False,
> 'size': 20971526, 'roth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isreg': True,
> 'pw_name': 'confluence', 'gid': 11667, 'ischr': False, 'wusr': True,
> 'xoth': False, 'rusr': True, 'nlink': 1, 'issock': False, 'rgrp':
> True, 'gr_name': 'confluence', **'path':
> '/confluence/home/logs/atlassian-confluence.log.4'**, 'xusr': False,
> 'atime': 1679735745.013214, 'isdir': False, 'ctime':
> 1681520175.011039, 'isblk': False, 'xgrp': False, 'dev': 64768, 'wgrp': False, 'isfifo': False, 'mode': '0640', 'islnk': False})

I'm able to filter out some string but it includes the text between `changed:`  and `'path:'`  as well. How can I filter out `changed: [hostname1] =>`  and `'path': (.*)`, only:

```
egrep -o  "changed: \[(.*)\] =>(.*) 'path': '([^,]*)'"
```

I tried also:

```
egrep -o  "changed: \[(.*)\] =>'([^('jira|confluence,)']*)' 'path': '([^,]*)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use alternative (`|`) to not match anything between:

```
changed: \[([^\]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'
```

Also note that I changed greedy `(.*)` to `([^\]]+)` (anything except `]`), which is much more reliable in case there are `]` further in the value.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvXI0x/1)

I also recommend running it with Perl syntax, so `grep -oP` instead of `egrep -o`.

Or, alternatively, don't escape the `]` with `egrep`:

```
egrep -o "changed: \[([^]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'
```

Comment: I tried `egrep -o  "changed: \[([^\]]+)\]|'path': '([^']*)'"` and it hit only 'path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-18--1900.zip' I would like it return `changed: [hostname1] => path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-18--1900.zip' `

Comment: Use `grep -oP` instead.

Comment: thank you , it works I run `grep -oP "changed: \[([^]]+)\] =>|'path': '([^']*)'" /tmp/936_job.log` the output return with new line in each hit like `changed: [hostname1] =>
'path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-18--1900.zip'` i would like to return all in one line like `changed: [hostname1] => 'path': '/mnt/nfs/jira/export/2023-Mar-18--1900.zip'`